# Insert text at caret position IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I want to be able to enter some text at the caret position. Currently I can insert text at the end or start of the textbox OR replace the whole textbox content with the new text. How can I get the new text to insert into the textbox at the caret position?

What I want:
i.e textbox contatins "12,3" with caret being where the coma is. After function call it ends up like so: "12new text3"

Current code:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("txtbox");
var text = "new text";

//ie 8
if (document.selection) {
 var range = document.selection.createRange();

   sel.focus();
   range = sel.createTextRange();
   range.collapse(false);
   range.text = text;
   range.select();
}
```

Comment: Made it clearer. Last paragraph is what I want.

Comment: The current code inserts the new text to the end of the textbox content. (i.e textbox contains 123, after function call it will contain 123newtext)

Answer (score 0):

I've not IE8 to test, but try this:

```
if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.text = text;
    range.select();
}
```

In your code you've defined `range` twice, and then collapsed the `range` (containing all the text in a textbox) to the end of the text.